# How to plot filled boxed around line and point in legend?

Tags: r, plot, legend

Some data

```
dummy.dt <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1000))

plot(dummy.dt, type="n", xlab="x" , ylab="y", xaxt = "n", log = "y")

legend("top", inset=.02, title="legend",
       c("1", "2"), 
       pch = c(1, 1), 
       lty = c(1, 1),
       col=c("blue", "orange"),
       fill=c(rgb(red = 200, green = 200, blue = 200, maxColorValue = 255, alpha = 50), rgb(red = 100, green = 100, blue = 0, maxColorValue = 100, alpha = 50))
       )
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The result I´d like to receive would be a filled box all around the lines.
How to manipulate the size of the filled box that is created by `fill`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first alternative, we keep the original length of the line segments and the corresponding 'long boxes' are made from lines. Create one legend with thick lines (the 'boxes'). Add a second legend on top with the thin lines and points:

```
plot(1)

# "filled boxes" made of lines
legend("top", inset = 0.02, legend = 1:2, title = "legend",
       lty = 1, lwd = 10, box.col = "white",
       pch = NA,
       col = c("grey90", "yellow"))

# lines and points
legend("top", inset = 0.02, legend = 1:2, title = "legend",
       lty = 1, lwd = 1, bty = "n",
       pch = 1,
       col = c("blue", "orange"))
```

[image]

A second possibility is to decrease the length of the line segments using `seg.len`. Then boxes are made from points. Please note that we need to specify the same `lwd` and `seg.len` in both legend calls, i.e. also in the call for the 'boxes' where `lty = 0`.

```
plot(1)

# "filled boxes" made of points
legend("top", inset = 0.02, legend = 1:2, title = "legend",
       lty = 0, lwd = 1, seg.len = 1,
       pch = 15, pt.cex = 2,
       col = c("grey90", "yellow"))

# lines & points  
legend("top", inset = 0.02, legend = 1:2, title = "legend",
       lty = 1, lwd = 1, seg.len = 1, 
       pch = 1, bty = "n",
       col = c("blue", "orange"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need `fill`at all. If you leave it out you will get only the lines plus the point character distinguished by color:

```
legend("top", inset=0.2, title="legend",
       c("1", "2"), 
       pch = c(1, 1), 
       lty = c(1, 1),
       col=c("blue", "orange")
   # fill=c(rgb(red = 200, green = 200, blue = 200, maxColorValue = 255, alpha = 50), 
   #        rgb(red = 100, green = 100, blue = 0, maxColorValue = 100, alpha = 50)
)
```

Comment: Yes, but i´m looking for a box around them. Similar to the one that `fill` is producing just bigger and aroun the entire line and point.

Comment: Then, probably, the answer that answers your question is @Henrik 's answer.